# What is the maximum number of units in StarCraft II: Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

In *Wings of Liberty*, the maximum number of units (based on the supply cap) was 200, but I found out that you can have up to 255 if they are added or found during gameplay.  What is the maximum number of units for *Heart of the Swarm*?  I am still in the download process so I cannot check myself.

Comment: In WoL you could have basically an infinite amount of units. 255 was just the limitation of units you could have in one control group but you could easily have 400 zerglings. In HotS the limit of units in the control group is removed.

Comment: Do not forget overlords. If something is infinite, they are.

Comment: One very important question - in campaign or in multiplayer?

Comment: I recall in BW if you mind-controlled a drone and an SCV you could build 200 supply for all 3 races.

Comment: Yes Ian, but in SC2 you only have 1 supply type even if you build other races buildings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One zergling take 0,5 supply (and this is the cheapest zerg unit) so you should have maximum number of **400 zerglings** on map.

Expansion:

After my small 45+ Blizzard minutes research **I gave up**.

[image: Over 300 Overlords]

I played custom with very easy Terran bot. I focus on building Overlords.

[image: Ending screen]

As you can see; 342 (unit produced) - 21 (unit lost) = **minimum 321 units alive in the same moment** . I don't receive any waring or other information that I can't produce more Overlords. So... you can have probably *max map* number of Overlords.

Max map number in **Starcraft II** is ([probably](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2913212728)) [4096](http://www.hiveworkshop.com/forums/starcraft-ii-editor-help-zone-647/maximum-number-units-map-212655/) so you can have max. **4096 Overlords**.

Comment: I'm not sure if this zergling take 0,33 supply :/

Comment: You might want to name the strain that gives this ability to complete the answer.

Comment: they don't take less supply, it's 1.5 supply by egg instead of 1

Comment: This seems to ignore the question being asked... He's asking whether there is a hard cap on unit number, and whether you can exceed the supply. Additionally, you forgot to factor in overlods/overseers, which are units that don't require supply.

Comment: @Sconibulus special update for you!

Comment: Yay! Super bonus answer! Victory!